# Why are saving throws not typically considered an action?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, saving-throw

It has been awhile since I played table top D&D, but I've always wondered why a player's "normal action" is not used up when making a saving throw?

When a round is 6 seconds long, it seem that (in some cases) saving from being blasted by a fireball, dragon breath, poisonous arrow, etc. would require you to make some kind of physical action (i.e., duck behind cover).

I think this topic becomes even more complicated when, let's say, your fighter is engaged in melee combat and is required to make some kind of wisdom save vs charm from an enemy caster.  Would that provoke an opportunity of attack because your fighter is distracted by mental voices coaxing to "join us?"

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se! Take a look at the [tour]; it's a useful introduction to the site. It seems like this is more an open discussion than a question. [Questions here have specific answers](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) rather than requesting general input. [Your question might be better suited to a forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go), as you'll get more helpful feedback in a place intended for open ended discussion.

Answer (score 5):

It's the same reason why things like "defending yourself from being attacked" don't take away your action. They are assumed to be occurring in the process of fighting and are abstracted out of the combat system.